# Two Identical A/C Units with Different Readings / Pressures not Stabilizing When Off

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cooling, central-air

I have two separate systems with one in the basement servicing the main floor, and the other in the attic servicing the upstairs.  The upstairs has been struggling in 90F heat ever since we moved in and I did some readings to see if I could come closer to determine if it was improper ducting (eg. I already know two of the upstairs rooms have no return duct), or something more serious.

Some initial information on the system:

- High Efficiency Fredders c1030bbd1v Rev W1
- R22
- Has the piston style metering device / superheat

Temperature during testing was 70F outdoors - not ideal

Here's a link showing the readings - https://imgur.com/a/YstoxIB.
Description below each image shows what it is (order is main floor off/on, then attic off/on)

Temperatures at the suction line - The main floor I was getting about 51F degrees on the line reading, but only about 66F on the attic line.

With that in mind, I do think it does need servicing, but what might be the possible issue here?  The readings look fine (albeit low?) when both systems are on, but the varying pressure on the attic gauges, as well as the line reading being high for superheat makes me wonder if it's refrigerant at the coil.

Appreciate any thoughts here.

[image]

Comment: So...gas and A/C downstairs, heat pump upstairs?

Comment: For R22 that's at 37f, not 66f. Which is more close to perfect (32) than you should be (~40) but it can't freeze so w/e, except (@70f?) : "slugging is usually the result of the compressor providing too much cooling capacity for the load in the space or not having enough heat content in the air to evaporate the liquid refrigerant." Man, I don't even remember how to check superheat. You hook the fancy gauge up and it tells you subcooling. Otherwise, math and stuff, and the installer's manual.

Comment: 65 pounds is *beer can cold; you're too old*. Get a fancy gauge. It's under charged. But I bet it *really* works for shit if it isn't pushing the limit as far as pos at near freezing. If it makes bad noises it could be *flashing in the coil*. - "It is perfectly normal (and *required*) that refrigerant “flashes” or begins boiling directly *after* the metering device and as it moves through the evaporator ..."

Comment: Pressures not Stabilizing When Off = clogged orifice. Be careful it doesn't shoot across the room when you take it off the coil that you can't unload the pressure from...

Answer (score 0):

Pressures not Stabilizing When Off = **clogged orifice**.

Make sure you **draw down from both sides of the system**. If you don't then the refrigerant in high side that's trapped between the orifice and the compressor will shoot the orifice at you when you take the nut lose.